# Batch file; Replace variable's spaces with hyphens

Tags: variables, batch-file, replace

I've started another small Batch project, however I've encountered a bit of a dilemma. I use `set name=` followed by `set /p name=`, to allow the user to give the input desired. However, I want the variable entered with spaces to then have the spaces replaced with hyphens (e.g. *"hello world"* becomes *"hello-world"*).

I've searched around and found many situations in which someone asks a similar question, however they are all using the `ren` command, which I have no use for due to not dealing with files.

My current code is as follows:

```
@echo off
Cls
echo Insert a string with spaces?
set string=
set /p string=
```

I have also found a solution for renaming files that mentioned using `ren "!file!" "!file:_= !"` to change a file name's spaces to underscores (`_`). However changing it to `set name=!name:-= !` didn't work for me.

How can I best replace spaces with hyphens in my batch file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're close.

```
@echo off
cls
echo Insert a string with spaces?
set string=
set /p string=
set string=%string: =-%
echo String is now %string%
```

See `set /?` for details on variable manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Also, I now see how setting a variable works, after the `:`, instead of acting off a guess. Thanks again!